# Conditional expectation by $\sigma (G_n,Y)$ when $Y$ is $G_\infty$-measurable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $G_n$ be a filtration (an increasing sequence of sigma-algebras), $Y$ a random variable that is $G_\infty$-measurable, and $X$ a random variable. Is it true that in $L^2$-norm,

$$ \mathbb{E}[X \mid \sigma (G_n,Y)]- \mathbb{E}[X \mid G_n] \stackrel{n \rightarrow + \infty}{\rightarrow} 0 $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Lemma** Let $X \in L^2$ and $(\mathcal{G}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a filtration. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_n) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_{\infty}) \quad \text{in} \, L^2$$ where $\mathcal{G}_{\infty} := \sigma(\mathcal{G}_n; n \in \mathbb{N})$.

*Proof*: Set $X_n := \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_n)$. Obviously, $(X_n,\mathcal{G}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale. Since the martingale is bounded in $L^2$, the martingale convergence theorem implies $X_n \to Y$ in $L^2$ for some random variable $Y \in L^2$. It remains to show that $Y= \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_{\infty})=:X_{\infty}$. By the tower property, we have $$\mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{G}_n) = X_n = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_n) = \mathbb{E}(X_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{G}_n)$$
Hence, for any $G \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{G}_n$: $$\int_G Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_G X_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P}$$ Since $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{G}_n$ is a generator of $\mathcal{G}_{\infty}$ which is stable under intersections, this implies
$$\int_G Y \, d\mathbb{P} = \int_G X_{\infty} \, d\mathbb{P}$$
for any $G \in \mathcal{G}_{\infty}$. By choosing $G := [\pm (X_{\infty}-Y)>0]$, we find $X_{\infty} = Y$ a.s. This finishes the proof.

---

The lemma shows that $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_n) \to \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_{\infty})$ in $L^2$. Applying the lemma for the filtration $\mathcal{H}_n := \sigma(\mathcal{G}_n,Y)$ yields $$\mathbb{E}(X \mid \sigma(\mathcal{G}_n,Y)) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{H}_n) \to \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{H}_{\infty}) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_{\infty})\quad \text{in} \, L^2$$ using that $\mathcal{H}_{\infty} = \mathcal{G}_{\infty}$ since $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}_{\infty}$-measurable. Consequently,

$$\mathbb{E}(X \mid \sigma(\mathcal{G}_n,Y))-\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{G}_n)\to 0 \quad \text{in} \, L^2.$$

Comment: In the first part, how do you know that $Y \in \mathcal{G}_{\infty}$?

Comment: @MatiasPuig Well, the OP *assumed* this, but actually we can always find a modifcation of $Y$ which is $\mathcal{G}_{\infty}$-measurable. Each $X_n$ is $\mathcal{G}_n$-measurable, hence $\mathcal{G}_{\infty}$-measurable. Since $X_n \to Y$ in $L^2$ we can choose a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ which converges almost surely to $Y$. This implies that $Y$ has a modifcation which is $\mathcal{G}_{\infty}$-measurable;

Comment: more precisely, $$\tilde{Y}(\omega) := \begin{cases} \lim_{k \to \infty} X_{n_k}(\omega), & \omega \in A, \\ 0, & \omega \notin A \end{cases}$$ where $$A := \{\omega; \lim_{k \to \infty} X_{n_k}(\omega) \, \, \text{exists}\}.$$ Note that $A \in \mathcal{G}_{\infty}$ as each $X_{n_k}$ is $\mathcal{G}_{\infty}$-measurable.